# php list array by random date

Tags: php, arrays, list, date, random

I need to list an array by date, this is what I have so far which spits out the image name and gives it a random date:

```
$images = glob('images/{*.jpg,*.gif,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($images as $image) 
 {
  $image  = str_replace('images/','',$image);
  $date   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '-'.mt_rand(0,1351).' days'));
  $result = $image . '<br />' . $date . '<br /><br />';

echo $result;

}
```

Example:

```
    16631824.jpg
    2008-04-23

    17122028.jpg
    2007-12-31

    1854815.jpg
    2007-10-13

    1gaffuv.jpg
    2009-04-12

    3rekel7c.jpg
    2010-06-13
```

Now I just need help listing it by date ...as always any help is appreciated.

Comment: how would you want your output to be ? can you give an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$images = glob('images/{*.jpg,*.gif,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE);

$sorted = array();
foreach($images as $image) 
{
  $image  = str_replace('images/','',$image);
  $timestamp   = strtotime('-'.mt_rand(0,1351).' days');
  $sorted[$timestamp] = $image;
}

ksort($sorted);

foreach ( $sorted as $timestamp => $image )
{
  $date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
  $result = $image . '<br />' . $date . '<br /><br />';
  echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Went with this one as I understood it better, but thanks to all that answered :)

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of images, using the date as the key, and then sort the keys before output.

```
$images_arr = array();
foreach($images as $image)
{
  $date   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '-'.mt_rand(0,1351).' days'));
  $images_arr[$date] = str_replace('images/','',$image);
}
// Sort on array keys
ksort($images_arr);

// Output your array however you need to
foreach($images_arr as $img)
{
  // output
}
```

Comment: Darn, I was typing too slowly and hsz beat me to the same solution :)

Comment: That always happens to me, Michael. :(